spring tool 4 parece que no toma la configuración que le aplico de Spring Security me vota una pagina en blanco
El problema es este estoy siguiendo una guía parar una escommerce en YouTube,el primer paso que realiza es configurar la seguridad y los cors ya lo realice una ves anterior mente pero tuve que volver a empezar el proyecto, la primera ves  funcionaba cuando yo buscaba http://localhost:5454/api me salia el login por defecto del sprint tool4 y cuando ponía http://localhost:5454 o cualquier otra  me salía un error 404 pagina not found  pero ahora no me sale nada  solo una pagina vacia eso si con estructura html pero puedo colocar http://localhost:5454/loquesea y aprece la misma pagina vacia, no se si se deba a un problema de configracion de mi spring toll o a una falla en el codigo por favor necesito ayuda esto es muy frustrante voy a adjuntar el codigo de AppConfig JwtConstant JwtValidator Jwtprovider.
AppConfig
package com.candyshop.config;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    
    
    @Bean
     SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests(Authorize->Authorize.requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll())
        .addFilterBefore(new JwtValidator(),BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors().configurationSource(new CorsConfigurationSource() {

            @Override
            public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
                
                CorsConfiguration cfg=new CorsConfiguration();
                
                cfg.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(
                    "http://http://localhost:3030",
                    "http://http://localhost:4200"
                        ));
                cfg.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                cfg.setAllowCredentials(true);
                cfg.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                cfg.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
                cfg.setMaxAge(3600L);
                return cfg;
            }
            
        })
        .and().httpBasic().and().formLogin();
        
        return http.build();
    }
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        
    }
    
} 


JwtConstant
package com.candyshop.config;

public class JwtConstant {
    public static final String SECRET_KEY="asdhawdihagydawiuddsadsadsawaiudaw";
    public static final String JWT_HEADER="Authorization";
}


JwtProvider
package com.candyshop.config;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;

@Service
public class JwtProvider {
    
    SecretKey key=Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(JwtConstant.SECRET_KEY.getBytes());
    
    
    public String generateToken(Authentication auth) {
        String jwt=Jwts.builder()
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date(new Date().getTime()+846000000))
                .claim("email", auth.getName())
                .signWith(key).compact();
        
        return jwt;
    }
    
    public String getEmailFromToken(String jwt) {
        jwt=jwt.substring(7);
        
        Claims claims= Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key).build().parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();
        
        String email= String.valueOf(claims.get("email"));
        
        return email;
    }
}


JwtValidator
package com.candyshop.config;
import java.util.List;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class JwtValidator extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        String jwt = request.getHeader(JwtConstant.JWT_HEADER);
        if(jwt!=null) {
            
            jwt=jwt.substring(7);
            try {
                SecretKey key=Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(JwtConstant.SECRET_KEY.getBytes());
                
                Claims claims= Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key).build().parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();
                
                String email= String.valueOf(claims.get("email"));
                
                String authorities= String.valueOf(claims.get("authorities"));
                
                List<GrantedAuthority>auths= AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(authorities);
                
                Authentication authentication= new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email,null,auths);
                
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                
            } catch(Exception e){
                throw new  BadCredentialsException("invalid token... from jwt validator");
            }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    
}

